# How to justify $\pm$ is unnecessary on both sides with respect to $x_1^2 = x_2^2 \implies \pm x_1 = \pm x_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

So I taught one-to-one functions in my class today and totally embarrassed myself with my explanation of trying to explain why you don't need to put $\pm$ on both sides for $$x_1^2 = x^2_2 \implies \pm x_1 = \pm x_2.$$

It doesn't tell the whole picture exactly. Why though? I was thinking about the following counterexample: $$(-3)^2 = (3)^2,$$ but I just got stuck trying to explain further. Why is this bad practice exactly?

Comment: No, it's not necessary in both sides. It is enough to write $\;x^2=y^2\iff x=\pm y\;$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having $\pm$ on both sides, but is not necessary either.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes but why is it sufficient?

Comment: It's simply redunant, which you can demonstrate by going through the four cases explicitly. No need to try to get fancy.

Comment: @Decaf-Math Because $\;x^2=y^2\;$ has **only two** solutions: either $\;y=x\;$ or else $\;y=-x\;$ . That's all...!

Comment: Moreover, if you only write $\pm x_1=\pm x_2$ and nothing else, this is often understood as the values of $\pm$ being the same in each instance. Therefore, it would be understood as $x_1=x_2$  and $-x_1=-x_2$, which is the same solution.

Comment: I think @orole 's explanation is what sparked the answer in my mind. Here's what I thought: $$x^2 = 9 \implies \pm x = \pm 3 \implies x = 3 \text{ or } -x = -3 \implies x = 3 \text{ or } x = 3,$$ which isn't all of the solutions we needed. Thanks everyone for providing your input, as it was valuable in helping me understand why this was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example says that squaring of the both sides gives an equivalent equality iff both sides have the same sign.

Actually, $$x_1^2=x_2^2\Leftrightarrow x_1=x_2\vee x_1=-x_2$$
 because
$$x_1^2-x_2^2=(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2).$$